# How to plot decision boundary in R for logistic regression model?

Tags: r, logistic

I made a logistic regression model using glm in R.  I have two independent variables.  How can I plot the decision boundary of my model in the scatter plot of the two variables.  For example, how can I plot a figure like [here](http://www.personal.psu.edu/jol2/course/stat597e/notes2/logit.pdf).

Comment: The link to the figure is dead.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
set.seed(1234)

x1 <- rnorm(20, 1, 2)
x2 <- rnorm(20)

y <- sign(-1 - 2 * x1 + 4 * x2 )

y[ y == -1] <- 0

df <- cbind.data.frame( y, x1, x2)

mdl <- glm( y ~ . , data = df , family=binomial)

slope <- coef(mdl)[2]/(-coef(mdl)[3])
intercept <- coef(mdl)[1]/(-coef(mdl)[3]) 

library(lattice)
xyplot( x2 ~ x1 , data = df, groups = y,
   panel=function(...){
       panel.xyplot(...)
       panel.abline(intercept , slope)
       panel.grid(...)
       })
```

[image]

I must remark that perfect separation occurs here, therefore the `glm` function gives you a warning. But that is not important here as the purpose is to illustrate how to draw the linear boundary and the observations colored according to their covariates.

Comment: I hope I am not old fashioned if I use lattice :-)

Comment: I also hope that if this is a HW problem, you will not simply copy paste.

Comment: Thanks. This is not a HW question and the answer is helpful for me to understand my model.

Comment: oh yes you are :)

Comment: Can someone explain me the logic behind the slope and intercept? (regarding the logistic model)

Comment: Very good exemple! thanks for this easy to understand code.

Comment: I got this part pretty easily, but I am interested in using a decision boundary other than 0.5; is there a straightforward way to shift the line based on the different decision boundary?

Answer (score 24):

Wanted to address the question in comment to the accepted answer above from Fernando: *Can someone explain the logic behind the slope and intercept?*

The hypothesis for logistics regression takes the form of:

$$h_{\theta} = g(z)$$

where, $g(z)$ is the sigmoid function and where $z$ is of the form:

$$z = \theta_{0} + \theta_{1}x_{1} + \theta_{2}x_{2}$$

Given we are classifying between 0 and 1, $y = 1$ when $h_{\theta} \geq 0.5$ which 
given the sigmoid function is true when:

$$\theta_{0} + \theta_{1}x_{1} + \theta_{2}x_{2} \geq 0$$

the above is the decision boundary and can be rearranged as:

$$x_{2} \geq \frac{-\theta_{0}}{\theta_{2}} + \frac{-\theta_{1}}{\theta_{2}}x_{1}$$

This is an equation in the form of $y = mx + b$ and you can see then why $m$ and $b$ are calculated the way they are in the accepted answer

Comment: Good explanation accompanying the answer above!

Comment: If we classify $y=1$ based on $h_θ ≥ t$ for a general $t$ between 0 and 1, we have $θ_0 + θ_1 x_1 + θ_2 x_2 ≥ \text{log odds}(t)$.