# Why logistic regression functions do not produce the right decision boundary?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, glmnet, separation

I created some data using the following code:

```
set.seed(1221)
x <- runif(500)
y <- runif(500, 0, 2)
z <- rep(0, 500)
z[-0.8*x + y - 0.75 > 0] <- 1
plot(x, y, col=as.factor(z))
```

This produces the following plot

[image]

The data is linearly separable. Then, I applied the `glm` function to create a logistic regression model.

```
df <- data.frame(class = z, x = x, y = y)
model <- glm(z ~ x + y, family = binomial, data = df)
```

This produces the following output:

```
summary(model)
Call:
glm(formula = z ~ x + y, family = binomial, data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-8.127e-04  -2.000e-08  -2.000e-08   2.000e-08   7.699e-04  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)    -1062      52666   -0.02    0.984
x              -1163      57197   -0.02    0.984
y               1433      70408    0.02    0.984

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 6.8274e+02  on 499  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1.3345e-06  on 497  degrees of freedom
AIC: 6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25
```

The result surprised me, first because the parameter estimates are huge, and second because I was expecting such estimates to be close to the original decision boundary function, i.e. `-0.8x + y - 0.75 = 0`.

I then used the [glmnet](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html) package to see if I could solve this issue. This package creates a penalised logistic regression model in order to deal with the large values in the parameter estimates. The code I used is the following:

```
library(glmnet)
cvfit <- cv.glmnet(as.matrix(df[,-1]), as.factor(df$class), 
                   family =   "binomial", 
                   type.measure = "class")
plot(cvfit)
```

[image]

And the coefficients for the optimal penalty strength are:

```
coef(cvfit, s = "lambda.min")
3 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                    1
(Intercept) -84.01446
x           -91.40983
y           113.18736
```

Such coefficients are smaller than the ones obtained with the `glm` function. Still they are not the same as the decision boundary function.

Does anybody know why this is happening? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Review posts bearing the tag Hauck-Donner effect.

Comment: Also note that the coefficients are log odds ratios - not of a decision boundary function. See [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/159977/17230). (In fact the decision boundary function derived from your logistic regression *is* pretty close to what it should be: I make it $0.81x + y - 0.74 = 0$.)

Comment: Thanks @user777 and Scortchi, following your advises I found an interesting [link](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression) that clarifies my question.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that @Scortchi I completely forgot the fact that the coefficients are log odds ratios. I was expecting to get the boundary function right away. Sorry, my mistake...

Comment: @jroberayalas: Don't be sorry. It's perhaps interesting to note here that even though the maximum-likelihood estimates are running away from each other, they're still constrained to give a sensible answer to your question. The Wald standard errors are the only thing that's unequivocally *wrong*.